# install Virtualbox on FreeBSD

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd

I need vitalization on FreeBSD server, and should import and OVA file.

Is it possible to install vBox on FreeBSD like Linux?

If yes, please tell me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FreeBSD Handbook would be a good starting point. This page describes how to install and configure VirtualBox on FreeBSD host.

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/virtualization-host-virtualbox.html